# PHP Array Returns Wrong Value

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, return, return-value

Now, $num here is just the number of lines of data from a database search. Sometimes, it will be 0. $procrastinate is a function argument.

```
if ($num==0) {
    return "Do not appear to be registered. Please check your email input again.";
    break 1;
} else { // there is an entry. check for consistency
    $procrastinateDB = mysql_result($result,0,'procrastinate');
    if ($procrastinate != $procrastinateDB) {
        return "Answer to your procrastination question is incorrect. Please try again!";
        break 2;
    }
    else {
        $username = mysql_result($result,0,'usrname');
        $passwd = mysql_result($result,0,'passwd');
        return array($username, $passwd, $num);
        break 2;
    }
}
```

What I'm not understanding is that even when $num=0, an array is still returned with $usersname = 'D', $passwd = 'o', and $num = ' '. Clearly, it's taking the first returned statement and just assigning these variables to each character in the first returned sentence in sequential order.

How do I stop this? I don't want $username, $passwd, $num to contain any value if there is no database entry.

Comment: Just a note: the `break` statements are useless here.  `return` already exits the function, so `break` is not needed.

Comment: @hakre: What are you talking about?

Comment: @Rocket: I was making jokes ;)

Comment: @hakre: Ah, guess I missed it, sorry.  My brain is kinda scrambled today, got a lot of work to do.

Answer (score 3):

Some comments about your code:

- You don't need to `break` after `return`.
- `break` does not work for `if` in PHP.
- You don't need to do `else` if you're using `return` already.

I made some changes to your code to make this more visible and it reduces the cyclomatic complexity as well. Probably this helps that you find your error easier:

```
function unnamed(/* ... unknown parameters ... */)
{
    /* ... some code ... */
    if ($num==0)
    {
        return "Do not appear to be registered. Please check your email input again.";
    }

    // there is an entry. check for consistency
    $procrastinateDB = mysql_result($result,0,'procrastinate');
    if ($procrastinate != $procrastinateDB)
    {
        return "Answer to your procrastination question is incorrect. Please try again!";
    }

    $username = mysql_result($result,0,'usrname');
    $passwd = mysql_result($result,0,'passwd');
    return array($username, $passwd, $num);
}
```

Your function returns a string or an array btw. If you don't check the return type and assume it's an array, you will trigger substring access (see it [documented on the string manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)):

```
$string = 'ABC';
echo $string[0]; // A
echo $string[2]; // C
```

It's often better to have a function return one type, not multiple. However this depends on your design and coding style, so I can only make suggestions, like return an object that contains a status message, a status code (success/failure) and - if available - the array of data you want to return. However that depends what you want / need. You can as well check the return type with [`is_array`](http://php.net/is_array) as well.

Comment: Thanks! Having clean code is good. What will you suggest as alternatives to returning different types?

Answer (score 1):

> an array is still returned with $usersname = 'D', $passwd = 'o', and $num = ' '.

When `$num` is 0, you are returning the string:

> Do not appear to be registered. Please check your email input again.

In PHP, you can access strings like arrays.  So, my guess is you didn't check to see if you were returned a string or an array, and did something like this:

```
list($username, $passwd, $num) = yourFunction();
```

Since strings can be accesed like arrays, `$username` would be `D`, `$password` would be `o`, and `$num` would be a space, as those are the 1st three characters.

I suggest using `is_array` before accessing the value to make sure you know what you're getting.

```
$ret = yourFunction();
if(is_array($ret)){
   list($username, $passwd, $num) = $ret;
}
else{
   // Something else
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using is_array to check. Now it works perfectly.

Comment: @shenge86: No problem.  Gotta be careful with PHP, variables can be of any type, so you need to make sure you know what each one is.